# How would I go about setting up a phone menu?

Tags: menu, google-voice

I apologize in advance since I think this question might be a bit broad, but I'd love if someone were to point me in the general direction of articles to read. I've been searching for information, but I haven't found anything helpful yet.

I'd like to try setting up an augmented reality game that requires players to call a phone number, receive an automated message, and input certain codes to the given number to receive hints.

What's the best way to go about setting up something like this? Is it possible to do with free numbers, like ones hosted on Google Voice? What languages / APIs / libraries are phone menus usually written in, and how are they hosted? If you have any experience working with these, are there any useful tutorials to get started? I'm a relatively competent programmer and feel comfortable learning whatever material might be necessary: I'm just at a loss regarding where to begin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A service that comes to mind is Twilio. Many actions, such as automatically responding to incoming SMSes, are possible with [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms). And one can import twilio modules in quite a few programming languages.